# Search Outlook before indexing finishes?

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a way to have complete search results in Outlook before it finishes indexing?

It currently tells me that "Search results may be incomplete because items are still being indexed." I need a way to tell it "Ignore index, just do a brute force search even though it might be slow". Like you can do in Windows Explorer...

Comment: Is it really still indexing, or are you having the common problem where it never finishes?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you don't have Outlook mail indexed. . .I'd check under Control Panel/Index options and make sure Outlook is included under "included locations."

Comment: I don't want to have mail indexed (it's an old IMAP folder that I've opened just to find a couple of emails). I want a "good old" unindexed search.